# Flink consuming s3 parquet file kyro serialization error

Tags: protocol-buffers, apache-flink, parquet

We want to consume parquet file from s3

My code snippet is like this. My input files are protobuf encoded parquet files. The protobuf class is Pageview.class.

```
import com.twitter.chill.protobuf.ProtobufSerializer;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.DataSource;
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.parquet.proto.ProtoParquetInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class ParquetReadJob {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        ExecutionEnvironment ee = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        ee.getConfig().registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(StandardLog.Pageview.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);
        String path = args[0];

        Job job = Job.getInstance();
        job.setInputFormatClass(ProtoParquetInputFormat.class);

        HadoopInputFormat<Void, StandardLog.Pageview> hadoopIF =
                new HadoopInputFormat<> (new ProtoParquetInputFormat<>(), Void.class, StandardLog.Pageview.class, job);



        ProtoParquetInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(path));
        DataSource<Tuple2<Void, StandardLog.Pageview>> dataSet = ee.createInput(hadoopIF).setParallelism(10);


        dataSet.print();
    }
}
```

There is always errors:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Serialization trace:
supportCrtSize_ (access.Access$AdPositionInfo)
adPositionInfo_ (access.Access$AccessRequest)
accessRequest_ (com.adshonor.proto.StandardLog$Pageview$Builder)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:730)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:109)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:22)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:730)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:113)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:761)
    at com.twitter.chill.Tuple2Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:42)
    at com.twitter.chill.Tuple2Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:33)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:761)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:315)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.plugable.NonReusingDeserializationDelegate.read(NonReusingDeserializationDelegate.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.serialization.SpillingAdaptiveSpanningRecordDeserializer.getNextRecord(SpillingAdaptiveSpanningRecordDeserializer.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.reader.AbstractRecordReader.getNextRecord(AbstractRecordReader.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.reader.MutableRecordReader.next(MutableRecordReader.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.ReaderIterator.next(ReaderIterator.java:73)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSinkTask.invoke(DataSinkTask.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:1055)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:109)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:22)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    ... 23 more
```

Can anyone advise my how to write batch processing program which can consume this kind of files?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue.
I found [this](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/75f5e0c1b64484b71d6e7dce95554d25cb194e48/flink-formats/flink-protobuf/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/formats/protobuf/NonLazyProtobufSerializer.java) and [this](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/75f5e0c1b64484b71d6e7dce95554d25cb194e48/flink-formats/flink-protobuf/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/formats/protobuf/ProtobufKryoSerializer.java) in a pending PR for flink-protobuf which solved it.

You would need to add the `NonLazyProtobufSerializer` and `ProtobufKryoSerializer` classes to your project
and register `NonLazyProtobufSerializer` as a default Kryo serializer for the Message type:

```
env.getConfig().addDefaultKryoSerializer(Message.class, NonLazyProtobufSerializer.class);
```

From the authors JavaDocs:

> This is a workaround for an issue that surfaces when consuming a DataSource from Kafka in a Flink
>    TableEnvironment. For fields declared with type 'string' in .proto, the corresponding field on the
>    Java class has declared type 'Object'. The actual type of these fields on objects returned by
>    Message.parseFrom(byte[]) is 'ByteArray'. But the getter methods for these fields return 'String',
>    lazily replacing the underlying ByteArray field with a String, when necessary.

Hope this helps.